# java prepared statement query is returning an error but If I print it and execute on the database directly it works

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following peace of code which is trying to create a query from an XML file and add it to a batch so I can execute large batch execute but its not working for me as I keep getting an error, so I tried to execute the preparedstatement without batching and keep getting an error saying:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'dept_no,  dept_name VALUES ('d009', 'Customer Service')' at line
>   1"

although when I debug the code I get that the query in the prepared statement is `INSERT INTO departments dept_no,  dept_name VALUES ('d009', 'Customer Service')` I dont know what is going on can someone advice please and help me to make it get executed as a large batch?

Here is the methods that I have:

```
public void invokePreparedStatement(QueryBuilder queryBuilder) {
    queryRunner = new QueryRunner();

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("INSERT INTO " + queryBuilder.getTableName());
    QName columns;
    String values;

    for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getColumns().size(); i++) {
        columns = (queryBuilder.getColumns().get(i));
        query.append(" " + columns.toString());
        if (i != queryBuilder.getColumns().size() - 1)
            query.append(", ");
        else
            query.append(" VALUES (");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getValues().size(); i++) {
        query.append("?");
        if (i != queryBuilder.getValues().size() - 1)
            query.append(", ");
        else
            query.append(")");
    }

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        preparedStatement = buildQuery(queryBuilder, preparedStatement);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public PreparedStatement buildQuery(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ");
    query.append(queryBuilder.getTableName() + " (");
    QName columns;
    String values;
    int counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getColumns().size(); i++) {
        getCoulmnAndValue(queryBuilder, query, i);
        if (i != queryBuilder.getColumns().size() - 1)
            query.append(", ");
        else
            query.append(") VALUES (");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getValues().size(); i++) {
        values = (queryBuilder.getValues().get(i));
        query.append(values);
        if (i != queryBuilder.getValues().size() - 1)
            query.append(", ");
        else
            query.append(")");
        counter = i + 1;
        ps.setObject(counter, values);
    }

    return ps;
}
```

Comment: Where you bind the Parameter?

Comment: where/when do you actually `set` the positional parameters? I don't see any `setXXX` invocations such as `setInteger` or `setString` etc

Comment: @javadba you can find in the buildQuery method at the end of the second for loop, I suspect this line but could not think of a better way to set the positioned parameters in a dynamic way as the query might have different number of parameters every time it gets called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your `queryBuilder` has table named `T`, with two columns named `A` and `B`. The generated SQL is then:

```sql
INSERT INTO T A,  B VALUES (?, ?)
```

That is not valid syntax, since the column names must be in `()`:

```sql
INSERT INTO T (A, B) VALUES (?, ?)
```

That is exactly what the error message is saying, when it is saying that the problem is near `A`, because a `(` is missing **right there**. Not just "near", but exactly there.

Instead of testing for `size - 1`, I'd suggest coding as follows:

```java
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("INSERT INTO ")
     .append(queryBuilder.getTableName())
     .append(" (");
for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getColumns().size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        query.append(", ");
    query.append(queryBuilder.getColumns().get(i));
}
query.append(") VALUES (");
for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilder.getValues().size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        query.append(", ");
    query.append("?");
}
query.append(")");
```

Comment: true that mate thank you for that, and one more thing why i cant use executeLargeBatch? it keeps saying that its not implemented I want to use it as I am trying to insert 4000000 records to the database in the fastest way

Comment: `executeLargeBatch` was adding in Java 8 and your driver was not updated to implement that method. Just use `executeBatch`, since each statement only insert one row anyway, the return values are all `1`, and will fit in an `int`. "large" is not about the batch size, but about return type `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: ok I see thank you very much, but my application is taking for ever to insert the queries that I have how can I improve its performance?

Comment: Improve performance by actually using `addBatch` and `executeBatch`, flushing the batch every 1000 inserts, to prevent out-of-memory.

Comment: I have done the following but still not very efficient: `try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
            preparedStatement = buildQuery(queryBuilder, preparedStatement);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }
            preparedStatement.execute();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: Why would you add the same insert statement 1000 times? You need to call setter methods inside the loop, to set the values for each statement added to the batch. --- Also, replace `execute()` with `executeBatch()`. --- Perhaps you should re-read the documentation on how JDBC batching works. --- And don't `commit` every 1000 inserts. You can defer commit until the end, unless database has a problem with too many inserted records.